# not able to create multi dimensional array in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I have the following code

```
public function get_request($requestid)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('instanthire as s');
    $this->db->join('instanthire_skills as ss', 's.id = ss.requestid');
    $this->db->where('s.id',$requestid);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

The resulting array that i am getting is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [userid] => 1
            [skills] => html
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [userid] => 1
            [skills] => core php
        )
)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [userid] => 2
            [skills] => Core Java
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [userid] => 2
            [skills] => Advance Java
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [userid] => 2
            [skills] => .net
        )
)
```

The issue is that for every userid the number of array increases with increase of skills, i wish to create one array for every userid and skills for that user should  be within the main array. can anyone please tell how i can correct my array

Table structure

instanthire

```
id  userid 
1     1
2     2
```

instanthire_skills

```
id  requestid  skills
1    1         html
2    1         core php
3    2         core java
4    2         advance
5    2         .net
```

desired output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [userid] => 1
            [skills] => Array
                (
                    [0] => html
                    [1] => core php
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [userid] => 2
            [skills] => Array
                (
                    [0] => core java
                    [1] => advance java
                    [2] => .net
                )
       )
)
```

Comment: can you share your db structure ? Is not possible with group by ?

Comment: @user1048123_SOreadytohelp updated my post

Comment: I doubt you’ll be able to write the SELECT statement in a way that result_array will automatically deliver the array structure you want. This is rather a job for a few lines of code, that take the data as it comes from the database, and then transform it into the desired target structure.

Comment: @CBroe can you please show me how it can be done

Comment: What’s with the id values, you only want to have the first id that occurred for the user id in your result array?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a single query that comes mind that will do what you want. You are going to have to do some processing after you retrieve values from the db.

My suggestion is to use the mysql function `Group_Concat()` to return a comma separated list (a string) of skills. You can `explode()` that to create an array of skills.

In this example I have dropped the use of table alias names because I get confused otherwise :)

Because your `where` clause will only return one row (There is only one row with any given `userid` value in `instanthire` - right?) I am using `$query->row_array()` to get the data. This simplifies the return to a single array as opposed to the array of arrays that `$query->result_array()` returns.

```
public function get_request($requestid)
{
    $this->db->select('instanthire.id, Group_Concat(instanthire_skills.skills) as skills');
    $this->db->from('instanthire');
    $this->db->join('instanthire_skills', 'instanthire.id = instanthire_skills.requested_id' , 'inner');
    $this->db->where('instanthire.userid', $requestid);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->row_array();
    $result['skills'] = explode(",", $result['skills']);
    return $result;
}
```

Let's assume you ran these two lines of code

```
$data = $this->get_request(2);
var_dump($data);
```

and inside `get_request()` after`$result = $query->row_array();` you added `var_dump($result);`  you would get this

```
array (size=2)
   'id' => string '2' (length=1)
   'skills' => string 'core java,advance,.net' (length=22)
```

and after `get_request()` returns `var_dump($data);` displays this

```
array (size=2)
  'id' => string '2' (length=1)
  'skills' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'core java' (length=9)
      1 => string 'advance' (length=7)
      2 => string '.net' (length=4)
```

If you want to process more than one `userid` then you will need a bit more code. Let me know if you need to see that.